# почему нельзя отправить несколько запросов await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id) в одной функции?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

есть три канала на которые нужно провести проверку через инлайн кнопку, я пробовал через цикл for, но он запускает команду только один раз

```
async def chan_check(call: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot):
done = True
chan = ["@канал1", "@канал2", "@канал3"]
for i in chan:
    result = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=i, user_id=call.from_user.id)
    if result.status == 'left':
        done = False
        break

if done:
    await call.answer("теперь вы участник!)")
else:
    await call.answer("вы не выполнили все условия!\nвыполните и попробуйте снова")
```

и пробовал через просто прямые условия

```
async def chan_check(call: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot):
chan = ["@канал", "@канал", "@канал"]
user_id = call.from_user.id
done = True
result1 = (await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chan[0], user_id=user_id))['status']
result2 = (await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chan[1], user_id=user_id))['status']
result3 = (await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chan[3], user_id=user_id))['status']

if result1 != 'left' and result2 != 'left' and result3 != 'left':
    done = True
else :
    done = False

if done:
    await call.answer("вы теперь участник!")
else:
    await call.answer('вы не выполнили все условия!')
```

что я не так делаю я не могу понять